# Solving problem concerning simple machines

Tags: physics

[image]

- An object with the weight of $80N$ is balanced with the force of $\vec {F}$ as seen on the diagram. What is the value of $\vec {F}$? (Ignore the weight of pulley and friction)

Resolving the components in $y$-axis.

The $y$-axis component of $F$ is $F\sin (37)$. It is balanced by the weight $80 N$.

$$F\sin(37) = 80$$

$$F = \dfrac{80}{\sin(37)} = \dfrac{80}{0.6} = \boxed {133.33 N}$$

However, there's no upward option of $50N$. Am I wrong?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intervening forces are

$$
\vec f_1 = f_0(0,1)\\
\vec f_2 = f_0(\cos(37\pi/180),\sin(37\pi/180))\\
\vec f_3 = h(-1,0)\\
\vec f_4 = 80(0,-1)
$$

and for equilibrium

$$
\vec f_1+\vec f_2+\vec f_3+\vec f_4 = 0
$$

giving

$$
f_0 =49.9433\\
h = 39.8865
$$

Comment: I really don't know what you did there.

Comment: $h$ and $f_0$ are the module forces involved. No more explanations.

Comment: They're wrong, you know?

Comment: If you say that, show me the solution then.

Comment: My teachers found this answer. However, should I have mentioned them $\sin 37 = 0.6$, $\cos = 0.8$?

Comment: $\sin(37^{\circ}) = 0.601815$ and $\cos(37^{\circ}) = 0.798636$

Comment: Can we say that $\dfrac{80}{\sin 37 + \cos 37}$?